Why woocommerce filters are not visible in my sidebar widget?
Im trying to implement filters to woocommerce site. When added it is showing them while editing page, but on normal view its not loading them at all. enter image description hereenter image description here
While editing page and checking it by inspect it looks normal, but on live its only generating something like that:
<div id="block-12" class="widget widget_block"><div data-block-name="woocommerce/filter-wrapper" data-filter-type="stock-filter" data-heading="Filtruj wg stanu magazynowego" class="wp-block-woocommerce-filter-wrapper"><div data-block-name="woocommerce/stock-filter" data-heading="" data-lock="{&quot;remove&quot;:true}" class="wp-block-woocommerce-stock-filter is-loading"></div><div data-block-name="woocommerce/stock-filter" data-heading="" data-lock="{&quot;remove&quot;:true}" class="wp-block-woocommerce-stock-filter is-loading"></div></div></div>
Have someone had something similar? If yes how did you fixed it?
I've checked wordpress logs for any errors but none have been logged, same for woocommerce logs. I've made sure that everything is correctly configured in woocommerce options, and also updated everything to be sure that files are good.
